# How to have a gradient blur in objects on Unity?

Tags: shaders, unity, mobile, blur

This is related to a previous question I've asked here:
[How to blur entire scene but a specific spot in Unity?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/115277/how-to-blur-entire-scene-but-a-specific-spot-in-unity/)

At the time I managed to solve my problem with a "hard" cutoff on the blurred and non-blurred objects. But now I need to have the same effect, but with some sort of "transition" between them, like the objects still being blurred at the edges of the circle "mask" I'm using and getting "non-blurred" as they get closer to the center.

As it is a mobile game, performance is really important, so is there any way of doing that without destroying my fps?

Thanks for your attention.